# Disable horizontal (left/right) mouse input during specific key press (toggle) or key hold

Tags: windows-10, mouse, macros, autohotkey, input-device

In Windows 10, I am looking for a way to disable any input from my mouse's movement in the horizontal or left/right direction while still allowing the input in the vertical or up/down direction to be recorded.

Allowing the mouse to only move in the up-down position and not move left and right. It would be ideal if this could be turned on and off either via some hotkey toggle or hotkey hold.

Example: While holding ']' or something similar, disable all horizontal input from my mouse being processed. After release, everything returns to normal.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: I assume OP either works in graphics design or plays games that require precision movements along a singular vector axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
]::
   CoordMode, Mouse
   MouseGetPos, x
   ClipCursor(x, 0, 0, A_ScreenHeight)
return

] Up::
    ClipCursor()  ; Off
return


; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=62856#p445668

ClipCursor(x := "", y := "", w := "", h := "") {
   if p := x != "" {
      VarSetCapacity(RECT, 16, 0), p := &RECT
      for k, v in [x, y, x + w, y + h]
         NumPut(v, p + 4*(k - 1), "Int")
   }
   DllCall("ClipCursor", "Ptr", p)
}
```

Comment: It's beautiful. Thank you.